# Show alert after each function that contains tx.executeSql

Tags: javascript, html, localdb

Hi I have this code in javascript:

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM table');
    var querys = texto.split('\n');
    $.each(querys, function(i,elem) {
        tx.executeSql(querys[i],[],null,null);
    });
    alert("DATA LOADED");
});
```

but my problem is that the alert is displayed before the tx.executeSql process has not finished inserting records... please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping your query inside `$.when` as below.

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM table');
    var querys = texto.split('\n');
    $.when(
    $.each(querys, function(i,elem) {
        tx.executeSql(querys[i],[],null,null);
    })).then(function(){;
          alert("DATA LOADED");
    });
});
```

You can also use `.done` instead of `.then`.

For more info visit **[this link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)**

Comment: OK thanks for the reply.... but how can I show the alert when all querys have been executed ... I do not want to show an alert each time a query is executed

Comment: Did you try executing the answer. That should work as you expect. First the query gets executed inside `$.when` and alert will be displayed from `$.then`

Answer (score 0):

Please see if it help for you. use the `executeSql` success and fail callback function.

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM table');
    var querys = texto.split('\n');
    var rowslength = querys.length;
    var insertedlength = 0;

    var callback = function(){
        if(insertedlength == rowslength){
        alert("DATA LOADED");
        }
    };

    $.each(querys, function(i,elem) {
        tx.executeSql(querys[i],[],function(){
        insertedlength++;
        callback();
        },function(){
        insertedlength++;
        callback();
        });
    });

});
```